# JSON loading not functioning in ePub3

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, epub3

I currently have a project where I am writing an ePub3 eBook.

I successfully included three.js to display some models. Now I want to create several 'hotspot' elements (small cubes which should be interactive to show details about the position on the model), by loading a JSON file in the following format:

```
{
  "detail0" :
  {
    "id": 0,
    "size" : [5, 5, 5],
    "coords": [-10 , 4 , -10],
    "text" : "first interactive object"
  },
  // ...
}
```

If I display the ebook in Safari everything is working, I can load the obj file and render it properly. Also parsing the JSON file works perfectly.

Same thing if I display it within iBooks for Mac.

But it is not working on my iPad in iBooks.

Does any of you has experience using JSON in ePub3?

In addition to this, is there a proper way of debugging ebooks except testing in browser and hoping for everything to work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Hi hGen @ epub3 format just for html page view not working in server side.

for Example: 
It support HTML5, Canvas, javascript, jquery, Svg, Gif, audio/video. it mostly interactivity type.

It not included localhost: Ajax, PHP, JSP, JSON etc.,

I hope u it's help for you.

Comment: Okay that might me a reason, is there another way of wiring a config file? the plugin I am writing should be working on different objects by just loading a file which tells the plugin what to load and what to do

Comment: Do you think XML would be working since all ePub3 config files are written in XML and the main format is xhtml?

Answer (score 0):

JSON works at EPUB-3 on iBooks. Download test book named "Create Dynamic Text and Footnote by JSON at EPUB-3" : http://teyid.org/testet/lib/?te=18072015

Comment: But what kind of parser is it using? Certainly not an Ajax parser